# Web Audio API - calculate cumulative gain of filters

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

`MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` is configured with several chained and overlapping `BiquadFilterNodes`. Each filter has different frequencies, gains and qualities. How can one calculate total gain of these biquad filters?

This gain is necessary to prevent clipping. Knowing the gain, I'll be able to add a GainNode to lower the volume to prevent clipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `BiquadFilterNode`, use `getFrequencyReponse` to get the frequency response of the filter, using the same `frequencyHz` array.  Each of these will have a `magResponse` array.  Multiply these together, element-wise to get the combined response.

Element 0 is the DC gain.  You could use this (the reciprocal) for the gain value of the GainNode.  But this might allow other frequencies to get clipped, so you might want to find the largest value in the combined response and use that.  However, this might cause the volume to be very low, depending on the filters being used.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made a public gist in case somebody else will need a solution: https://gist.github.com/chebum/1f901ebcdb2b55489065a90267ce5fc6

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for producing the code to go with my words.  Only thing I might add is to have the function take an extra arg to specify the spacing.  The `steps` value should probably be derived from the sampleRate, which you can get from one of the filters by looking at the `filter.context.sampleRate`.